# Android multiple dialogs to one OnClickListener

Tags: android, switch-statement, android-alertdialog

Is it possible to assign a single `OnClickListener` to one `AlertDialog`?

Here is the dialogs itself:

```
        AlertDialog.Builder dialog1 = new AlertDialog.Builder(PrefActivity.this);
        dialog1.setTitle("Dialog 1");
        dialog1.setPositiveButton("ok" , myListener);

        AlertDialog.Builder dialog2 = new AlertDialog.Builder(PrefActivity.this);
        dialog2.setTitle("Dialog 2");
        dialog2.setPositiveButton("ok" , myListener);
```

And here is the listener:

```
        DialogInterface.OnClickListener myListener = new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                switch (???){
                    case dialog1:
                    break;

                    case dialog2:
                    break;
                }
            }
        };
```

What should I write in those `switch-case` statement to correctly determine which dialog was picked?

Comment: What is purpose of this way of dialog's?

Comment: try passing `dialog` to your `switch()` statement.

Comment: Sathish, because I don't want to write same `OnClickListeners`, which differs only it one-two row.

Comment: Sripad, I've tried, but it's not working, I'm getting errors.

Comment: can you post what error you're getting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't show the dialog directly, build a dialog and assign it to a variable like:

```
dialog1 = new AlertDialog.Builder(PrefActivity.this);
dialog1 = builder1.create();
dialog2 = new AlertDialog.Builder(PrefActivity.this);
dialog2 = builder2.create();
```

set the same listners

```
new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
@Override
public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
      if(dialog == dialog1){
            //Dialog 1
      } else if(dialog == dialog2) {
            //Dialog 2
      }
 }
```

Comment: Thanks, this it what I need. There is no way I can check it with `switch-case`, rather than `if-else`?

Comment: I believe not. I haven't tried with switch yet. But you can try with switch(dialog.hashCode()) and use dialog1.hashcode() in switch cases.

Answer (score -1):

1.Simply create a new class i.e `myListener` and implement  `DialogInterface.OnClickListener` interface

2.Create constructor with int argument

3.Pass reference of a new  class instead of interface and pass int argument which will be later use in switch statemnt i.e `dialog.setPositiveButton("OK",new myListener(int))`

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {
static int dialog1 = 1;
static int dialog2 = 2;
Button button, button2;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
    button2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);

    button.setOnClickListener(this);
    button2.setOnClickListener(this);
}

@Override
public void onClick(View view) {
    if (view == button) {
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        builder.setTitle("Dialog 1");
        builder.setMessage("this is first dialog");
        builder.setPositiveButton("ok", new myListener(dialog1));
        builder.show();
    }
    if (view == button2) {
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        builder.setTitle("Dialog 2");
        builder.setMessage("this is second dialog");
        builder.setPositiveButton("ok", new myListener(dialog2));
        builder.show();
    }
}


class myListener implements DialogInterface.OnClickListener {
    int dialogNo;

    public myListener(int dialogNo) {
        this.dialogNo = dialogNo;


    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
        switch (dialogNo) {
            case 1:
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Dialog first", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                break;
            case 2:
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Dialog second ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                break;
        }


    }
}
}
```